# How to get date (Ymd His) from JSON which formats /Date()/

Tags: php, json, date

I am calling an function from remote server which outputs me in XML format. By processing it with PHP and decoding it with JSON (json_decode) I get following output:

`print_r($data);` gives..

stdClass Object ( [CreatedDate] => /Date(1360641338000-0600)/ [DateOfBirth] => /Date(1360558800000-0600)/ )

How can I get `CreatedDate` in `Y-m-d H:i:s` format?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339140/json-date-object-to-php-date?rq=1

Comment: Why do you process xml as json?

Comment: @PLB don't ask that. I know I could have used SimpleXML, but now I am in a position I can't changes things :(

Comment: @MagenTools: That is a very bad idea to mix JSON & XML, but since you already introduced that problem and cannot solve that, you will have bad times (depending on what you will need to process). This specific format will require you to parse it separately (there is no built-in, clean support for this format). You could extract first number in brackets and treat it as Unix timestamp in miliseconds, and extract the second number treating it as timezone offset (`+/-HHMM`). Use offset for timezone setting, and change miliseconds into seconds - the rest is very easy.

Comment: @Tadeck agreed. that's why I asked it here after spending much time to get heck outta it!

Comment: @Rikesh thanks! solved it by referring that solution. if you can put that in answer I will accept it!

Comment: @MagenTools - It's Fine. Answer on this post won't be helpful to anyone in future as it's already there on SO. So you can delete your post.

Comment: @MagenTools Actually, this question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Rikesh I have modified it to match my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved by referring to another SO question's solution as pointed by Rikesh in his comment. Modifying it a bit to match my requirement. I am answering this just to help some frustrated soul landing here to find the solution.

```
$startDate = $data->CreatedDate;
preg_match( '/([\d]{10})/', $startDate, $matches );

$sd = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $matches[0] );
$startDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($sd) - 3600 * 6); //adding 6 hours to match server's time
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON has no specific Date data type. The API you are using appears to be returning a string that it expects you to `eval` in JavaScript.

You'll need to process the string to remove the `Date(` and `)` parts, then split on `-` (and possibly also on `+`) and subtract (or add) on from the other. Then you can use standard [date and time functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).