# Parsing a *supposed* Unix date time (with timezone info) to DateTime object

Tags: c#, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have a supposed Unix date format coming through in a json feed from a third party that looks like this:

> /Date(1391741913713+1100)/

Is there any way I can parse that to a `DateTime` object?
I'm not convinced this is a "true" Unix dateTime object...

Looking at the accepted answer to this question: [How to convert a Unix timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa) 
The parsing method takes a double... my string contains +1100 (as well as the outder /Date()/ part)

Comment: It's not a unix timestamp integer. It's number of milliseconds since unix epoch

Comment: That's what I thought, despite the third party insisting it is.... edited question to reflect this.

Comment: Well, third party has no idea what they are talking about then :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3339237/251311

Comment: Ah, that looks interesting.... the regex may help me out.... let me try that

Comment: To be scientifically correct: is there a definition of the "Unix timestamp"? It's by convention that we know it refers to the number of seconds since 1970. But you can express a "Unix timestamp" (meaning a timestamp showing the time elapsed since the Unix epoch) in milliseconds as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens, when parsing from JSON using JSON.net, this is handled automatically